# Sort a dictionary using an the value and an if statement

Tags: swift, dictionary, binary, integer

I am new to Swift and I am trying to go out on my own and create my own "app."  I am creating an "app" that I can take a dictionary of players:ranking and sort them into three tiers based on the ranking.  I keep getting errors and cannot figure out why.  I searched through Stack Overflow and other documentation and still can't figure it out.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4tNLF.jpg)

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: It doesn't make sense to "sort" a dictionary.  Instead, you should encapsulate your data in some way (via a `struct` or `class`), this would then allow you to sort an array, which would be much easier

Comment: No pictures of code please.

Comment: `playerValues` is an array of the values in the dictionary

Answer (score 0):

`playerValues` is an array of values. You cant expect to compare it to an `Int`

Try

```
for person in playerKey {
    if player[person] > 1035 {
       tierA.append(person)
    } else if player[person] > 1021 {
       tierB.append(person)
    } else {
       tierC.append(person)
    }
```